# Can someone please explain this syntax in Razor to me?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

Honestly I've looked for quite a while and I can't even find the general format for what I'm looking for, but I have the following Razor syntax that I do not have any idea on what it means.

```
<option value="@value" @(Model.Amount == value ? "selected" : "") >$@value</option>
```

I'd like an explanation of that line of code if possible. In specific, why do I not have 
option value ="@Model.Amount" or something like that?
I also dont understand how the Razor syntax works in terms of what comes after Model.Amount == value

What does the '?' indicate
As well as the two values "selected" : "")

If someone could thoroughly explain this to me I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: What `@(Model.Amount == value ? "selected" : "")` does is that it checks if the option value is equal to Model.Amount, and if it is equal, it will add a "selected" attribute to the option tag. But, 
this is a bad way of creating drop-down lists. You should use `Html.DropDownListFor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(condition) ? (if true) : (else)` is the C# [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not just for Razor.

It writes out `<option value="xxx" ... "selected">` if `@value` is equal to `Model.Amount`, i.e. selecting it in HTML.

It is equivalent shorthand to

```
if (Model.Amount == value)
{
   <%: "Selected" %>
}
else
{
  <%: "" %>
}
```

Comment: Hey Stuart, thanks for the answer, now if I had a text box would this be the appropriate syntax to pass it back to my controller then?    
            <input type="text" name="autoThreshold" id="autoThreshold" value="@Model.AutoReloadThreshold" placeholder="">

Comment: Yes, that would insert `@Model.AutoReloadThreshold` into the value attribute of the input. Give it a try and see :)

Comment: hmmm maybe I'm doing something wrong but when I have that, the value in the textbox is not sent to my model in the post method.

Comment: Easiest way to debug these is usually to analyze the network traffic that the browser sends up to the server. [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) and [IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/04/22/ie9-developer-tools-network-tab.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
value="@value"
```

This is setting the value of the option

```
@(Model.Amount == value ? "selected" : "")
```

This is shorthand boolean logic, or IF/THEN
The above is conceptually the same as this:

```
if (Model.Amount == value)
{
    return "selected";
}
else
{
    return "";
}
```

The View's model has a property on it named Amount, and this is a boolean used to determine if the option is the selected value in the select.